# Managed bean not called in Icemobile

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces, icefaces-3

I am new to Icemobile, but since it promises fast development on mobile devices I gave it a shot.  I use Netbeans for development, Netbeans 7.1 on one PC and Netbeans 7.3 on another.

The problem is that with Netbeans 7.1, a managed bean is not called on post back.  It is constructed and getters are called on the initial GET page.  On Netbeans 7.3 this is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I later found that in Netbeans 7.1, the JSF library is JSF 2.1 with jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar , whereas in Netbeans 7.3, it is JSF 2.2 javax.faces.jar.  I substituted this jar in the Netbeans 7.1 machine and problem solved.

I think icesoft.org should state this caveat in http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEmobile/supported-platforms.jsf.  Here it only says JSF 2 Mojarra.

Also although the web site states Tomcat 7 is required, I found Tomcat 6 is OK so far (although some functionalities may not be supported on Tomcat 6)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that we've done any specific testing with ICEmobile with Mojarra 2.2. I would recommend sticking with Mojarra 2.1 for now. Despite the version the NetBeans version is defaulting to, you can override that just by including the javax.faces.jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder so that it's always included in the war file. As for Tomcat, I don't believe that we say that Tomcat 7 is required. We actually support a very wide range of application servers. Check out our supported platforms page (http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEmobile/supported-platforms.jsf).

The issue you were having with managed beans not being called sounds strange, and I would guess that it's more likely due to JSF configuration than ICEmobile. We'd be happy to take a look at your app and configuration.

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: The site you quoted DOES say Tomcat 7. For Mojarra version see my comments below.

Comment: I still have problem: clicking the submit button does not call the managed bean's setter method (should be logged).  The program and tomcat output are in https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e5BhWOwW8v1METFu43wx_b31q8ze9Af6VAarZFA4Kpo/edit?usp=sharing I have included javax.faces.jar, jstl-1.2.jar, tlddoc.jar, icefaces-mobi.jar, icefaces.jar, icemobile-jsp.jar, icepush.jar, all these are in the icemobile download bundle.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to posting your app, which version of the ICEfaces Netbeans plugin are you using? http://www.icesoft.org/java/downloads/icefaces-downloads.jsf.

What are the exact version numbers of the Mojarra jars you've been using for both 2.1 and 2.2?

Comment: I had problem when using NetBeans 7.1.2 (without ICEfaces Netbeans plugin) and Mojarra 2.1.6.